# WebComponents: Remove cloned template

Tags: javascript, html, clone, web-component

I'm using the webcomponentsjs polyfill. No x-tag, polymer, etc. preferably vanilla JS.

After cloning a template and appending it to the document I'm not able to remove it again since it's missing a parentNode.

```
var tmpl = document.getElementById('tmpl');
var clone = document.importNode(tmpl.content, true);
document.body.appendChild(clone);
console.log(clone.parentNode); // parentNode is null (not undefined!)
clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone); // fails!
```

[You may see yourself in this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lokopiyiha/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

My Question is: How do I remove the element again. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) vs. [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). The `content` of `template` is apparently an instance of `DocumentFragment`:

```
<template>
  <div>node 1</div>
  <p>node 2</p>
  etc
</template>
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), `Node#appendChild` accepts document fragments:

> Various other methods can take a document fragment as an argument (e.g., any Node interface methods such as `Node.appendChild` and `Node.insertBefore`), **in which case the children of the fragment are appended or inserted, not the fragment itself**.

So, what do you expect to be a parent of document fragment? It’s obviously null, since the entity “document fragment” is virtual in this context. So, to achieve what you want you are to create a container at first, and then append nodes to it / clean it’s content up.

```
<body>
  ...
  <div id='container'></div>
  ...
</body>
```

There is common approach to add template content involving ShadowDOM:

```
var shadow = document.querySelector('#container').createShadowRoot();
shadow.appendChild(document.querySelector('#tmpl').content, true);
```

or not using ShadowDOM, inserting as is:

```
document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(
  document.querySelector('#tmpl').content, true
);
```

Hope it helps.